# Duplicate rows of pandas dataset

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset  like this:

```
text          dialog      class_1     class_2     
hi              1            0           1
how are you?    1            0           1
I'm find        0            1           0
And You?        0            1           0

I want to transform the dataset like this:

word         dialog      class_1     class_2     
hi              1            0           1
how             1            0           1
are             1            0           1
you             1            0           1
?               1            0           1
I'm             0            1           0
find            0            1           0
And             0            1           0
You             0            1           0
?               0            1           0
```

Basically I have a column containing the sentences (text). I want to split it into a column with all the words, keeping the columns: dialog and class with the same attributes.

My dataset is create by pandas library.

My code:

```
ct=0
sentences2=[]
for j in dataset['text']:
        sentences1=str.split(dataset.iloc[ct][0])
        sentences2.append(sentences1)
        ct=ct+1

i=0
ii=0
new_dataset=[]
for q in dataset.iloc[i]:
    for qq in sentences2[ii]:
        new_dataset.append(pd.concat([dataset.iloc[i]]*len(sentences2[ii]),ignore_index=False))
        if(i<=len(dataset)):
           i=i+1
        if(ii<=len(sentences2)):
           ii=ii+1
```

The loop stop when i=5 and ii=5. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `DataFrame` is called `df` you use `stack` and `reset_index` together with join.

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame(
        df.text.str.split().tolist(), index=df.index
    ).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).join(df)
```

You might have to find a better way to split the text (split() is splitting by spaces). You can use any regex in the split function.

Comment: Thank you very much